# jboss EAP 6.3.3 fallback authentication

Tags: jboss, spnego

I have an app to deploy that requires SSO to work off AD. This is working with the following snippets:

jboss-web.xml

```
<security-domain>java:/jaas/SPNEGO</security-domain>
<valve>
  <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>
</valve>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api" slot="main"/>
  <module name="org.jboss.security.negotiation" />
  <module name="sun.jdk" slot="main"/>
</dependencies>
```

domain.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
  <security-domains>
    <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
      <authentication>
        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
          <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
          <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
      </authentication>
    </security-domain>
    <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
      <authorization>
        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
      </authorization>
    </security-domain>
    <security-domain name="host" cache-type="default">
      <authentication>
        <login-module code="Kerberos" flag="optional">
          <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/spn.xx.xx@xx.xx"/>
          <module-option name="keyTab" value="/xx/xx/xx.keytab"/>
          <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
        </login-module>
      </authentication>
    </security-domain>
    <security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
      <authentication>
        <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="requisite">
          <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
          <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
          <module-option name="removeRealmFromPrincipal" value="true"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="sufficient">
          <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
          <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
          <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://xx.xx.xx:389"/>
          <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=xx,ou=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx"/>
          <module-option name="bindCredential" value="xxencryptmexx"/>
          <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx"/>
          <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(&amp;(samaccountname={0})(objectclass=user))"/>
          <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
          <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
          <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx"/>
          <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
          <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
          <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="false"/>
          <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="2"/>
          <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
        </login-module>
      </authentication>
    </security-domain>
  </security-domains>
</subsystem>
```

I would like to deploy the same app to another server with a different profile without changing the jboss-web.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml to have a fallback authentication to use the databaseserverlogin module. This app will then be used by others to make RPC calls to it (no SSO). I tried stacking the login-module below:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
  <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/MyDatabaseDS"/>
  <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd from Users where username=?"/>
  <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select userRoles, 'Roles' from UserRoles where username=?"/>
  <module-option name="ignorePasswordCase" value="true"/>
</login-module>
```

The error I'm getting running a wget command (in hoping that it will fallback to databaseserverlogin module)

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Unknown authentication scheme.
Authorization failed.
```

I can successfully use the databaseserverlogin module by itself, but not without stripping out the **valve** entry in jboss-web.xml.

Is this setup possible? I'm trying to avoid modifying the WAR file received from development.

I tried the following [link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SECURITY-448) but stuck on class not found org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationWithBasicFallbackAuthenticator? I assumed the patch would have been included in latest jboss EAP 6.3.3? Probably a bad assumption.

Thanks in advance for any guidance (and patience if I'm not making sense).

Answer (score 2):

Sorted, with help from RedHat Support.

•To enable fallback to basic, add the following to the top of the WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
  <description>BASIC Authentication FallBack</description>
  <param-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator.BasicAuthFallBack</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Link to newly created knowledge base solution here if you have RedHat support
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1488173